# why are my cloud firestore triggers not working using the GUI?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a firestore cloud function however I'm getting the error failed to configure trigger providers. I've included some relevant screenshots.

I've also tried using different paths like '{collection}/'{document}' and 'users/farout' however only the explicit 'users/farout' was able to deploy however when i make a document 'users/farout' it doesn't print anything to the log and appears to not be working either.

My database is public read and write.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you using quotes in the document path?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Well I feel incredibly stupid >.>

I thought I tried it without quotes. I've been trying to get this to work for 3 hours now. Thanks so much haha!